# Detect two forms of empty elements in XML using .Net

Tags: .net, xml, xmlreader

I've run into an issue with parsing XML in .Net where I need to be able to detect which form of empty element I have but can't seem to get this to work correctly.  Essentially in the XML format I'm parsing the following two fragments should parse differently:

```
<sometag />
```

and

```
<sometag></sometag>
```

My problem is that .Net does not appear to provide me with any means to determine the different between the above.

Using DOM based parsing the `XmlNode` will report '""' for both the `InnerText` and `InnerXml` and the `OuterXml` property expands to the second form regardless of the input XML so no way to detect based on that.

<s>Using `XmlReader` based parsing both forms report `IsEmptyElement` to be `true` and I can't see any other properties of any use to detect this.</s>

Anyone know of any way to detect this for DOM based parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case `IsEmptyElement` returns `true` when you are at the start element and in the second case it returns `false`:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "sometag")
    {
        // prints true if <sometag/> and false if <sometag></sometag>
        Console.WriteLine(reader.IsEmptyElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Corrected my question, you are right that this does report appropriately for `XmlReader` based parsing, would still be nice to be able to detect the same for DOM based parsing

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but what is *DOM based parsing*?

Comment: Document Object Model = DOM .  If you are using the `XmlDocument` class then .Net will turn the entire XML document into a tree of objects which depending on your XML format can make parsing easier since you can move freely through the data rather than forward only.  The downside is that it requires far more memory than doing `XmlReader` parsing especially if you have large XML files